# Why won't the Office 2007 key work?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, license-key

I'm trying to replace an old machine.  The new machine is installed and running other than Office which is giving me license key fits.  While the disks for other software were at hand nobody knows with Office.  Unlike some of the similar questions I do have the old drive.

Magic Jellybean run against the old drive says it's Microsoft Office Standard 2007.  Ok, I grabbed the installer for 2007 standard (the legit .EXE versions, not anything from a torrent site) and put the key in--no go.  Just in case something was strange I grabbed all 5 versions, still no go.

Since the machine also has Office 2003 Small Business installed I don't think this could be an OEM version.  The place is way to small and IT-weak for it to be a volume license.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Edit:  The error message is:

The key is incorrect.  Verify that you have the correct key, and then retype it.

I get exactly the same error no matter which version I use it on.  Doing it with internet access disabled doesn't change anything.

As for where the files are from, this is a post with links to all 5.  I've used the official images from that site before without problem.

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/22621-Microsoft-Office-2007-%28Official%29-Direct-Download-Links

Edit:  Belarc, Magic Jellybean and Nirsoft's keyfinder all agree on the license #.

Comment: What's the error message you get when you use the license key?  Maybe they've used the license key on too many systems?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting all 5 versions of Office 2007 from exactly?  I have in the past have verified that the key that Magic Jellbean claims is the license for certain products to be 100% incorrect.  I would hook up the old hdd, run Belarc Advisor, and make sure you have the right license key.

Comment: I will be honest it sounds like the license key you have is not actually a legit license key.  Do you have another license key ( an entirely different one ) that you can try?

Comment: @Ramhound If I hadn't pulled it off a working installation I would agree it's no good.  How would a working installation have a bad key, though?

Comment: @LorenPechtel - There are "cracks" that disable the authentication process of the key and will accept any license key that is in the valid format.  The fact you think that there is even a possibility the license key could be invalid indicates there might be other pirated software used.

Comment: @Ramhound The only reason I think it might be invalid is that they aren't big enough to have an IT department that watches such things.  There's also certainly nobody there that could have cracked it but obviously I have no way of ruling out the actions of other unscrupulous individuals.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - Which is the reason I suggested verify an entirely different computer.  If it has the same license key then its either pirated copy or you are dealing with a volume license and need to verify the license to the KVM server instead.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, I see what you mean!  I can't check other machines in the office until tomorrow, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the key number is correct, what did Produkey say was the actual product ID?  Whomever installed it could have:  Bought his own copy (Retail media & key), installed an OEM copy (OEM), gotten it from a System Builder CD, downloaded it from Technet/Action Pack (Volume License), warez or cracked site (keygen)...  Search based on the product key to see what version you had installed.

Comment: I think you nailed it--the product ID shows it to be a volume license.  I can't imagine that being legit but I can't actually verify that yet.

Comment: Could have come from Technet/MSDN - they sometimes used VL keys.  You could try and obtain a VL media and install.  If it gets flagged or something, you can try and call Microsoft.  Don't know that they'd like the media and original COA being lost, but who knows.  Worst case and they say stolen/keygen/pirate... you can always state that this was some sort of inherited system.  They may offer a "get legit" discount.  You could take it or just tell them you plan to wipe the program.